# Solve Second Order Differental Equation With Disrete Values

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$y''+2y'+\alpha y=0$, where $\alpha$ is a real constant, and with boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(5)=0$.

For some discrete values of $\alpha$, the equation could have non zero solutions.  Find the three smallest values such that it has non zero solutions.

Ok so I started this problem by letting $y=e^{mx}$, so then I have

$[m^2+2m+\alpha]e^{mx}0$ so then $m=-1+\sqrt{1-\alpha}$ and $m=-1-\sqrt{1-\alpha}$, so then I have

$0=C_1e^{-x+\sqrt{1-\alpha}x}+C_2e^{-x-\sqrt{1-\alpha}x}$

Here, if $y(0)=0$ then $C_1=-C_2$, then if

$y(5)=0$ and I don't figure anything out about the constats so I'm loss.  Any help is apprciated,thanks

Comment: Hmmm I seemed to have messed up before but I'm still a little bit stumped.  So I have $e^{-5(\sqrt{1-\alpha}+1)}=e^{5(\sqrt{1-\alpha}-1)}$, take the ln of Noth sides then divide by 5, so $-\sqrt{1-\alpha}+1=\sqrt{1-\alpha}-1$ , then $\alpha=1+1=2$ and $\alpha=1-1=0$, which is only two values.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous equation $y^2+2y+\alpha=0$ has the solutions $r_1=-1+\sqrt{1-\alpha},r_2=-1-\sqrt{1-\alpha}$. Let's consider three cases.

**Case 1: $\alpha<1$**

If $\alpha<1$, then the homogeneous equation has 2 real roots, and so the solution is 
$$y(x)=C_1e^{(-1+\sqrt{1-\alpha})x}+C_2e^{(-1-\sqrt{1-\alpha})x}$$
and by plugging the boundary values, we get
$$\begin{align}
y(0)&=C_1+C_2&=0\\
y(5)&=C_1e^{-5+5\sqrt{1-\alpha}}+C_2e^{-5-5\sqrt{1-\alpha}}&=0
\end{align}$$
which is fairly easy to see has the unique solution $C_1=C_2=0$ when $\alpha<1$. So there is no non-zero solution for this case.

**Case 2: $\alpha=1$**

If $\alpha=1$, then the homogeneous equation has a double root, and so the solution is 
$$y(x)=C_1e^{-x}+C_2xe^{-x}$$
and by plugging the boundary values, we get
$$\begin{align}
y(0)&=C_1&=0\\
y(5)&=C_1e^{-5}+C_25e^{-5}=C_25e^{-5}&=0
\end{align}$$
which again is easy to see that $C_1=C_2=0$. So there is no non-zero solution here either.

**Case 3: $\alpha>1$**

If $\alpha>1$, then the homogeneous equation has two complex root, and so the solution is 
$$y(x)=C_1e^{-x}\sin(x \sqrt{\alpha-1})+C_2e^{-x}\cos(x \sqrt{\alpha-1})$$
and by plugging the boundary values, we get
$$\begin{align}
y(0)&=C_2&=0\\
y(5)&=C_1e^{-5}\sin(5 \sqrt{\alpha-1})+C_2e^{-5}\cos(5 \sqrt{\alpha-1})=C_1e^{-x}\sin(5 \sqrt{\alpha-1})&=0
\end{align}$$
Now let's observe the final equation $C_1e^{-5}\sin(5 \sqrt{\alpha-1})=0$. If we have a non-zero solution, then $C_1\neq0$, so $\sin(5 \sqrt{\alpha-1})$ must be zero instead. The sine function is zero at integer multiples of $\pi$, so we have the equation
$$5\sqrt{\alpha-1}=n\pi,n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\implies\alpha=\frac{\pi^2n^2}{25}+1$$
However, if $n = 0$, we get $\alpha=1$, which is a different case, and negative integer values of $n$ give the same value of $\alpha$ as positive integers, so the full set of non-zero solutions to the boundary problem is the values of $\alpha$ such that
$$\alpha=\frac{\pi^2n^2}{25}+1,n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Since $\alpha$ is real, we have covered all possible cases, and so the 3 smallest values of $\alpha$ that produce non-zero solutions are
$$\begin{align}
\alpha_1&=\frac{\pi^2}{25}+1\\
\alpha_2&=\frac{4\pi^2}{25}+1\\
\alpha_3&=\frac{9\pi^2}{25}+1\\
\end{align}$$